# Sharing an Excel sheet online and edited by more than one user

Tags: web-apps, microsoft-excel

I want to share an excel sheet ( Editing Entries, New Entries ) over through online. More than two users will have the rights to do this.

I heard of Google docs, but just looking for better option.

Comment: What do you miss in Gdoc?

Comment: If you want something "better" than GDocs you have to define "better" - personally for all my use cases I've ever had GDocs was perfectly fine.

Comment: If you have a shared access location (network drive, or SharePoint for example) you can simply used the native excel sharing functionality...protection and shared sheets etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're missing some native features of Excel, Microsoft now provides their own cloud-based collaborative editing solution in Office 365 and OneDrive/SkyDrive.

Comment: i am not looking for cloud based solution. i wonder any web interface to export the excel and give user rights to my users

Comment: This question has been closed because you did not include these requirements. You should edit your question to clarify for the comments that have been made, and then flag it to be reopened, otherwise reputation isn't calculated.